# R, Setting up a loop to continuously collect JSON

Tags: json, r

I am trying to set up an R script that will continuously collect JSON data(every 15secs throughout the day) from OpenSky's REST API.

I am trying to adapt this [script meant to collect Car2Go data](https://github.com/JunWorks/car2go/blob/master/TimedgetData.R).

I think I have the basics for the loop, however, I am confusing myself in combining all the data into on dataframe that will can write to a csv at the end up the day.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

for (day in 1:100){

  flight.df.time <- data.frame()

  for (i in seq(1,5760)){
    rm(flight.df)

    flight.df <- data.frame()

    all_flights <- fromJSON('https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all')

    # Creates df from JSON and filters lat/long to DC Metro Area
    dc_flights <- as.data.frame(all_flights$states) %>%
      mutate(V6 = as.numeric(levels(V6))[V6],
             V7 = as.numeric(levels(V7))[V7]) %>% 
      filter(between(V6, -78.361647, -75.872761),
             between(V7, 38.197760, 39.646129))

    flight.df.time <- rbind(dc_flights, flight.df)

    print(Sys.time())
    Sys.sleep(15)

  }

  write.csv(flight.df.time, file = paste(day, '_flight.csv', sep = ''))
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me get the loop to continuously add data to the data frame and not overwrite it like I am doing now? Thanks!

Comment: in `write.csv`, `append=TRUE` should get you where you need to go.

Comment: append doesn't seem to work for write.csv anymore. Works fine with write.table. I reworked the code a bit but append was the answer in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

flight.df.time <- data.frame(icao24 = character(), 
                         callsign = character(), 
                         origin_country = character(), 
                         time_position = double(), 
                         time_velocity = double(),
                         longitude = double(), 
                         latitude = double(), 
                         altitude = double(), 
                         on_ground = character(), 
                         velocity = double(), 
                         heading = double(),
                         vertical_rate = double(), 
                         sensors = character(), 
                         Time = character(),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

write.table(flight.df.time,'G:/DCIST/OpenSky/Data/flight_week.csv', sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)

for (day in 1:100){



  for (i in seq(1, 8640)){
    rm(flight.df)

    flight.df <- data.frame()

     flight_url <- 'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all'

    tryCatch({
      all_flights <- fromJSON(txt = flight_url)
    }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})

    dc_flights <- as.data.frame(all_flights$states) %>%

      select(-(V14:V18)) %>% 

      mutate(V6 = as.numeric(levels(V6))[V6],
             V7 = as.numeric(levels(V7))[V7],
             Time = Sys.time()) %>%

      filter(between(V6, -78.361647, -75.872761),
             between(V7, 38.197760, 39.646129))

    flight.df.time <- rbind(dc_flights, flight.df)

    write.table(flight.df.time,'G:/DCIST/OpenSky/Data/flight_week.csv', append = TRUE, sep = ",", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

    print(Sys.time())
    Sys.sleep(10)

 }


}
```